# Opentracing - Should I trace internal service work or just API calls?

Tags: opentracing

Suppose I have service which does the following:

1. Receives input notification
2. Processes input notification which means:

   - some computing
   - storing in DB
   - some computring
   - generating it's own notification
3. Sends its own notification to multiple clients

What is the best practice in this case, should I granularly trace each operation like computing, storing in db etc with separate span or leave that for metrics (i.e. prometheus) and create single span for the whole notification processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat up to you as to the granularity that's appropriate for your application, and also the volume of tracing data you're expecting to generate. An application handling a few requests per minute is going to have different needs than one handling 1000s of requests per second.

That said, I recommend creating spans when control flow enters or leaves your application (such as when your application starts processing a request or message from an external system, and when your application calls out to an external dependency, such as HTTP requests, sending notifications, or writing/reading from the database), and using logs/tags for everything that's internal to your application.